# looping through an array of objects using node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am new with using mongodb and node am trying to loop through an array of objects from my database and display only the objects using a res.json, in my console.log it displays all the object, but in my postman using res.json it displays only one object please help

**MY CODE**

```
const course = res.GetUserDT.coursesHandled;
  for (let index = 0; index < course.length; index++) {
            console.log(course[index]);
        }
```

```
const course = res.GetUserDT.coursesHandled;
  for (let index = 0; index < course.length; index++) {
            res.json(course[index]);
        }
```

**my console output**

```
{ courseCode: '2103' }
{ courseCode: '2012' }
{ courseCode: '2062' }
```

**my postman output**

```
{ courseCode: '2103' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only send `res.json` once.

To send all of them together you can create an array, push all the objects in the array and send it back as a response.

```
let arrayToReturn = []
for (let index = 0; index < course.length; index++) {
   arrayToReturn.push(course[index])
}
res.json(arrayToReturn);
```

**Update**

@David's answer is the most accurate solution i.e just directly send the array as a response instead of looping

```
res.json(res.GetUserDT.coursesHandled);
```

Comment: You're welcome but david's answer is more simple and accurate because there is no need for loop unless you need some modification.

Comment: it worked but how do i pull all the courses from the array and display as separate data

Answer (score 3):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.

The Problem here is that `res.json()` sends a an immidiate response to the requestor - meaning a response is sent already within the first iteration of your for-loop.

I am also wondering why you need that loop - as you are not doing anything within it. So why don't you just send the array immidiately like so:

```js
res.json(res.GetUserDT.coursesHandled);
```

Comment: I missed that in my answer. This should definitely be the accepted answer if you are not doing any array modifications!

Comment: This is the perfect answer and should be included in the accepted ones.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is express, res.json() will send the data and end the response.

try something like:

```js
 const responseArray = [];
 
 for (let index = 0; index < course.length; index++) {
    responseArray.push( course[index] ); 
 }
 res.json(responseArray);
```